# C# load external dll with embedded images

Tags: c#, image, dll, resources

I've a tiny application with several icons. I decided to put them in a separated DLL, so within my solution, I created a project and I've embedded those icons as resources.
Then I compiled this library (myImages.dll)

After, I added that dll as reference in the main program and I used the ResourceManager to get the reference of my custom library. Then I pointed to use GetObject method to retrieve the name of each file.

The following code works, but an error occurs when I try to retrieve an icon:

```
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("myAssembly.MyNamespace", Assembly.LoadFile("Images.dll"));
Image myImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(rm.GetObject("myIcon")));
```

Seems that the reference to my Images.dll doesn't work properly.
Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you get resources by name, you need to provide a fully qualified name. If you call [GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx), you can get a list of the names in your loaded resource manager to easily find out exactly what the names area that you must use.